# Error running npm start and creating React application using npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have node and npm install on my system but when i try to use npx to create react-app or even run npm start for node application i see the error below.
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ReactApp\my-app.

```
The term '/d' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
 or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included
, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ /d <<<<  /s /c npm --version
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/d:String) [], CommandNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



DELL@DELL-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/ReactApp
$ npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ReactApp\my-app.

The term '/d' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
 or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included
, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ /d <<<<  /s /c npm --version
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/d:String) [], CommandNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation. Solution is to just restart your newly downloaded Visual Studio Code and it will get the right path to the NPM and Node.